# phpmyadmin mysql INSERT statement syntax error

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I don't know what's wrong, why my statement won't insert. I have the following data:

```
username varchar length (25)
password varchar length (25)
fname varchar length (25)
email text
contactnum big int (30)
```

I don't know why my email is not inserting along with my contactnum
here's the screenshot:
[image]

Based on what I understand the length is the number of characters in a data one can enter right?

What seems to be wrong on my query?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO members (username, password, fname, email, contactnum)
VALUES (2, 2, 2, 'have@gmail.com', 1)
```

if its string dont forget to use single quotation

Answer (score 0):

The string value you're inserting into the **email** filed needs to be quoted. Also, the names of the table and columns *shouldn't* be quoted. The query should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO members (username, password, fname, email, contactnum)
VALUES (2, 2, 2, 'have@gmail.com', 1)
```

Note that the first three fields you're changing are declared as varchar, so  you should be inserting strings into them as well. The reason you're not getting errors for trying to insert integers into varchar fields is that in some cases the wrong data type can be automatically converted. I think it's better practice not to rely on implicit type conversions, to avoid errors and unexpected results, so the query really should be written this way:

```
INSERT INTO members (username, password, fname, email, contactnum)
VALUES ('2', '2', '2', 'have@gmail.com', 1)
```

That's a matter of opinion, though. They both work.

Comment: Thanks :) am i right? about the length values, is the character count(digits) that you can enter? for example int age lenth value (2), you can only enter two digit like 11, entering 111 will give an error right?

Comment: @Daryl Correct, the length is the maximum number of characters allowed in the field.

Comment: @MichalČihař Yes, you're right, thanks. I'll remove that advice (which was kind of an aside anyway, not really part of the answer).